# jquery datatables not redrawing on reload

Tags: datatables

My datatable is not drawing the data when I putt `success` in the ajax call? how can i make it draw the table?

```
table_impact = $('#table_impact').DataTable({
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    title: 'Details of Service Impact'
                }, 
                'print'

            ],
            'bDestroy': true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            'iDisplayLength': 10,              
            "bSort": false,
            searchHighlight: true,
            ajax: {
                url: base_url + 'api/change/self-serve',
                type: "POST",
                data : function(d){
                    d.action = "impact";
                    d.period = $("#group_period label.active").data("value");
                    if($("#checkbox_in_flight").prop("checked")){           
                        d.inflight = 1;
                    }else{
                        d.inflight  = 0;
                    }

                    coordinator_group = $(".js-basic-multiple-coordinator-group").val();
                    if(coordinator_group && coordinator_group.length > 0){
                        d.coordinator_group = [];
                        for( key in coordinator_group){
                            var obj = coordinator_group[key];
                            d.coordinator_group.push(obj);                                          
                        }
                    }
                    change_manager_group = $(".js-basic-multiple-change-manager-group").val();
                    if(change_manager_group && change_manager_group.length > 0){
                        d.change_manager_group = [];
                        for( key in change_manager_group){
                            var obj = change_manager_group[key];
                            d.change_manager_group.push(obj);                                           
                        }
                    }
                    company = $(".js-basic-multiple-company").val();
                    if(company && company.length > 0){
                        d.company = [];
                        for( key in company){
                            var obj = company[key];
                            d.company.push(obj);                                            
                        }
                    }
                    status1 = $("#ticket_status").val();               
                    if(status1 && status1 != 'null' && status1.length > 0){
                        d.status = [];
                        if(typeof status1 == "string"){
                            d.status = status1.split(",");
                        }else{
                            for( key in status1){
                                var obj = status1[key];
                                d.status.push(obj);                                         
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                    ops_cat_tier1 = $(".js-basic-multiple-ops-cat-tier1").val();
                    if(ops_cat_tier1 && ops_cat_tier1.length > 0){
                        d.ops_cat_tier1 = [];
                        for( key in ops_cat_tier1){
                            var obj = ops_cat_tier1[key];
                            d.ops_cat_tier1.push(obj);                                          
                        }
                    }
                    pou_id = $(".js-basic-multiple-pou").val();
                    if(pou_id && pou_id.length > 0){
                        d.pou_id = [];
                        for( key in pou_id){
                            var obj = pou_id[key];
                            d.pou_id.push(obj);                                         
                        }
                    }
                    customer_ref = $(".js-basic-multiple-customer_ref").val();
                    if(customer_ref && customer_ref.length > 0){
                        d.customer_ref = [];
                        for( key in customer_ref){
                            var obj = customer_ref[key];
                            d.customer_ref.push(obj);                                           
                        }
                    }
                    incident_id = $(".js-basic-multiple-incident").val();
                    if(incident_id && incident_id.length > 0){
                        d.incident_id = [];
                        for( key in incident_id){
                            var obj = incident_id[key];
                            d.incident_id.push(obj);                                            
                        }
                    }
                    impact = $(".js-basic-multiple-impact").val();
                    if(impact && impact.length > 0){
                        d.impact = [];
                        for( key in impact){
                            var obj = impact[key];
                            d.impact.push(obj);                                         
                        }
                    }
                    change_id = $(".js-basic-multiple-crq").val();
                    if(change_id && change_id.length > 0){
                        d.change_id = [];
                        for( key in change_id){
                            var obj = change_id[key];
                            d.change_id.push(obj);                                          
                        }
                    }
                    project_ref = $(".js-basic-multiple-project").val();
                    if(project_ref && project_ref.length > 0){
                        d.project_ref = [];
                        for( key in project_ref){
                            var obj = project_ref[key];
                            d.project_ref.push(obj);                                            
                        }
                    }   
                },
                success : function (e){
                    console.log(e);
                    if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(e.error)){
                        if (e.error.message.indexOf("Allowed memory size of") >= 0){
                            // show error message
                            $('#alert-modal-title span').html("Details of Service Impact");
                            $('#alert-modal-body').html("Search query is too large, please use filters to narrow results!");
                            $('#alert-modal').modal('show');
                            $(".dataTables_empty").html("Search query is too large, please use filters to narrow results!");
                            $("#table_impact_processing").hide();
                        }
                        console.log(e.error);
                    }
                    //table_impact.draw();
                },
                "error": function(e) { //404 errors and the like wil fall here
                    //"throw new Error('Some error')"
                    console.log(e);
                }
            },
            columns: [
                    { "data": "CHANGE_ID" },
                    { "data": "SCHEDULED_START_DATE_GMT" },
                    { "data": "SCHEDULED_END_DATE_GMT" },
                    { "data": "POU_ID" },
                    { "data": "SUMMARY" },
                    { "data": "STATUS" },
                    { "data": "COMPANY" },
                    { "data": "CUSTOMER_PID" },
                    { "data": "SITE_GROUP" },
                    { "data": "SERVICE_STATUS" },
                    { "data": "CIRCUIT_ID" },
                    { "data": "ADDRESS" },
                    { "data": "SERVICE_IMPACT" },
                    { "data": "SERVICE_TYPE" },
                    { "data": "SERVICE_MODEL" },
                    { "data": "OTHER_REF" },
                    { "data": "TAIL_REF" },
                    { "data": "KEY_OWNER" },
                    { "data": "RECEIVES_COMMS" },
                ],          
        });
```

If i remove the success part it draws the data fine.

Comment: I think this `ajax` option is not `ajax` of jQuery. This is datatable option. Maybe you can use `drawCallback` instead of `success`. https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was looking for an error, I moved it to error part

```
table_impact = $('#table_impact').DataTable({
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend:    'copyHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Copy'
            },
            , {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                title:  'Summary of Changes',
                text:   '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                titleAttr:  'Excel'
            }

        ],
        'bDestroy': true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        'iDisplayLength': 10,
        "oLanguage": {
        },
        "bSort": false,
        searchHighlight: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        'bScrollCollapse': true,
        'sScrollX': '100%',
        'scrollX': true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        ajax: {
            url: base_url + 'api/change/self-serve',
            type: "POST",
            data : function(d){
                d.line_type = 'fixed';
                d.action = "impact";
                if($("#group_period label.active").data("value") == null){
                    d.period = "custom";
                    d.period_custom = $("#reportrange span").html();
                }else{
                    d.period = $("#group_period label.active").data("value");
                }


            },
            /*success : function (e){
                console.log(e);

                table_impact.draw();
            },*/
            "error": function(e) { //404 errors and the like wil fall here
                //"throw new Error('Some error')"
                var error = JSON.parse(e.responseText);
                if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(error.error.message)){
                    if (error.error.message.indexOf("Allowed memory size of") >= 0){
                        // show error message
                        $('#alert-modal-title span').html("Details of Service Impact");
                        $('#alert-modal-body').html("Search query is too large, please use filters to narrow results!");
                        $('#alert-modal').modal('show');
                        $(".dataTables_empty").html("Search query is too large, please use filters to narrow results!");
                        $("#table_impact_processing").hide();
                    }
                }else{
                    $('#alert-modal-title span').html("Details of Service Impact");
                    $('#alert-modal-body').html("An error has occured, please contact Support");
                    $('#alert-modal').modal('show');
                    $(".dataTables_empty").html("An error has occured, please contact Support");
                    $("#table_impact_processing").hide();
                }
            }
        },
        initComplete: myCallBack
    });
```